# how to store files using MongoDb C# Norm

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

Can someone help me with a complete sample how to store a file using MongoDB, C# and Norm and manage the limitation size. I have read some ideas about but is not really clear for me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing files you should look at using GridFS which handles the sizing problems for you. You can read about the general spec here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification

For NoRM specifically you can check out the tests that are part of NoRM - this one is particular:

https://github.com/atheken/NoRM/blob/master/NoRM.Tests/GridFS/GridFileCollectionTests.cs